# python timer based on datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to program for a simple game. I want the countdown to be printed like 10, 9, 8, ... for seeing how much time is left to collect items. when the timer runs out I want the program to close.
This is the error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
```

can sombody correct it or better send me a working timer concept?
Thanks

```
import time
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
later = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = int(later - now)
#countdown in sec
tcount = 10 

countd = tcount - diff
countd = str(countd)

while diff < tcount:
    print("countdown:" + countd)
```

Comment: Have a look at [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait a little in your loop.

Comment: even with this error fixed, your main issue is that your are producing an infinite loop. you have to update "diff" in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get time that has passed is by using time.time()

```
import time
now = time.time()
# do some stuff
elapsed time = int(time.time() - now)
```

In terms of measuring a second, maybe have it pool time time using time.time(), and then have a loop to check when the current time minus that pooled time is greater than 1. That will be one second. Repeat for as many seconds as needed.

Edit:
Or duh, just use time.sleep() like a comment suggested. time.sleep(1) will sleep for 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, `later - now` is a `datetime.timedelta`.  If this were assigned to a variable, say `diff_delta`, then `diff_delta.total_seconds()` would give you its value in seconds.

Comment: total_seconds is a function so it must be called to produce result